# UITableViewCell subview constraints problem - When are constraints updated in differen iOS Versions?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have created a custom `UITableViewCell` which contains a subview that uses its layer settings to create round corners. The corner radius has to be half the height to be completely round.

Since the height is not known when creating the view, I override `layoutSubviews()` to update the corner radius to the correct value.

Problem is, that the outcome is different between different iOS Versions and between iPhone and iPad. While the corners are always correct on iPhone, they are only correct on iPad when using iOS 15. When using iOS 14 or 13 on iPhone the corners are square:

[image]

It seems that on iPhone in and on iPad with iOS 15 `layoutSubviews()` is called twice for each cell. On the first call the `clippingView` frame is zero and thus the corner radius is zero. On the second call the `clippingView` frame has its final size and thus the corner radius is calculated correctly.

On iPad with iOS 14 and 13 the second call to `layoutSubviews()` is missing. So here the corner radius is calculated from the zero rect and thus zero as well.

Why is this?

**Is there any reliable method to update the corner radius after layout both on iPhone and on iPad and in all iOS 13+ versions?**

While I understand that layout might be handled differently between different iOS versions, why is it handled differently between iPhone and iPad?

---

**Code:**

```
class CardCell: UITableViewCell {
    private var clippingView: UIView!
    private var titleLabel: UILabel!
    
    var title: String? {
        get { return titleLabel?.text }
        set { titleLabel.text = newValue }
    }
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        
        clippingView = UIView()
        clippingView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(clippingView)
        
        clippingView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        clippingView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        clippingView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
        clippingView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
        
        clippingView.layer.cornerRadius = (clippingView.frame.height * 0.5)
        clippingView.backgroundColor = .red
        
        
        titleLabel = UILabel()
        titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        clippingView.addSubview(titleLabel)
        
        titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: clippingView.topAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        titleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: clippingView.leadingAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        titleLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: clippingView.bottomAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
        titleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: clippingView.trailingAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        clippingView.layer.cornerRadius = (clippingView.frame.height * 0.5)
    }
}
```

Comment: I think there is should be duplicate, but I wasn't able to find it. You need subclass clipping view and set corner radius in its layoutSubviews

Comment: Thanks a lot, this indeed solved the problem! Would you like to post an answer I can accept? I will share my solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the hint by @Cy-1AH I was able to solve the problem. The solution is to use a `UIView` subclass as clipping view and update the corner radius in `layoutSubviews()` of this class:

```
class CardCell: UITableViewCell {
    // ... see complete code in question
    private var clippingView: ClippingView!

    class ClippingView: UIView {
        var didLayoutSubviews: (() -> Void)?
    
        override func layoutSubviews() {
            super.layoutSubviews()
            didLayoutSubviews?()
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        clippingView = ClippingView()
        // ...
        clippingView.didLayoutSubviews = { [unowned self] in
            self.clippingView.layer.cornerRadius = self.clippingView.frame.height * 0.5) 
        }
    }
}
```